# Should the BRE tag be a synonym of biztalk-rule-engine?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, synonym-request

There are two tags that were being used for very similar purposes: [bre](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bre) and [biztalk-rule-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/biztalk-rule-engine).
When I first looked BRE was a generic tag about Business Rules Engine and it was being used both for one question about PHP and several about the BizTalk Business Rules Engine.

I've re-tagged all the BizTalk-related ones as [biztalk-rule-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/biztalk-rule-engine) and the PHP one as [rules-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rules-engine).

Should the BRE tag be a synonym of [biztalk-rule-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/biztalk-rule-engine)?

If so how is that done?

I probably don't have enough rights to do it.

Comment: In response to "How is that done?" and you probably not having enough rights, [you do need 2,500 rep before you can propose tag synonyms.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) As a side note, tagging this as [synonym-request] might help your cause.

Comment: I've marked up the tags; not seeing any questions tagged [tag:BRE] though.

Comment: And here I thought BRE meant "Basic Regular Expressions" (one of the flavors of POSIX regular expressions).

Comment: If you find that people type `bre` when they mean the BizTalk Business Rules Engine, then there should be a synonym from [tag:biztalk-bre] to [tag:biztalk-rule-engine].  The former will automatically get suggested when someone types `bre`, and people presented with that option shouldn't have any doubt whether it applies to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[bre](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bre) has been deleted.

<kbd>[image: bre tag missing from search]</kbd>

When you retagged the questions to [biztalk-rule-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/biztalk-rule-engine), you left [bre](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bre) without any questions. When a tag has no questions when the [tag deletion script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19753/how-can-we-get-rid-of-misspelled-and-unused-or-zombie-tags) runs, it is deleted. That said, this tag can still be re-created, but given how few questions it already had, I'd say this is unlikely.